# How I can add a new formControl in nested formBuilder in the Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-formbuilder

I have the following form that created with Angular FormBuilder :

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        'name': ['', [Validators.required],
        'surname': ['', [Validators.required],
        'email': ['', [validateEmail]],
        'address': fb.group({
            'street': [''],
            'housenumber': [''],
            'postcode': ['']
        }, { validator: fullAddressValidator })
    });
}
```

How I can add a new formControl in the address programmatically?
(With using `addControl` I get the `Property 'addControl' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'` error)

Comment: Firstly you should cast your AbstractControl to FormGroup or FormArray

Comment: `(this.myForm.get('address') as FormGroup).addControl(...)`